# Changing the location of Mathematica in Wolfram Workbench (Eclipse)

Tags: workbench

I have installed Wolfram Workbench. But I get the error message, that eclipse can't find Mathematica 9.0. I have no MMA 9.0 installes, I have only 12.2 on my PC.

Comment: You can add more `Mathematica` versions in Window->Preferences->Wolfram.